# List products by their author - Woocommerce Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, list, woocommerce, author

I do not know whether you can help me or not but I need your help.

I have tried a lot of things to list products by their author on my web-site, however, I failed.

I want it so that when people click on author's profile, they can see the author's products.

If anyone knows to write this code, please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give some more specifics about our problem and what you have tried so far?   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Products in WooCommerce are simply posts with a custom post type. As long as you assign the author capability (example taken from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/74331)):

```
add_action('init', 'wpse_74054_add_author_woocommerce', 999 );

function wpse_74054_add_author_woocommerce() {
    add_post_type_support( 'product', 'author' );
}
```

Then it's trivial to list posts by an author, using code like this:

```
$args = array(
    'author'     =>  $author_id,
    'post_type'  => 'product'
);

$author_posts = get_posts( $args );
```